# Expected 1 argument, but got 2 (ts 2554) on custom validator

Tags: typescript, validation

I've got the following validator and when adding it I get this error.

Expected 1 argument, but got 2 (ts 2554).

When reading about it I mostly see overloading is the issue, but there's no overload here.

```
export const customValidatorAsync = (co: CustomObject, id: string): AsyncValidatorFn =>
return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    ...
});
```

And then implementing it like this (this field is in a group of fields added as users add more instances):

```
setFieldValidators(index: number): void {
    const array = <FormArray>objectRegistrationForm.controls["children"];
    const group = <FormGroup>array.controls[index];
    group.controls["field"].setValidators([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.maxLength(20)],
    [customValidatorAsync(customObject, objectRegistrationToSave.children[index].id)]);
}
```

This validator previously did not need the id as users could not modify data. But now the data should be checked if it is not used by a different object. So I need the current id (which will be empty when creating a new registration, so id can be null))

Have checked that I do get the expected data, but don't get why this validator now gives this error. Hovering over the import shows me that it wants 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong thing...

```
setFieldValidators(index: number): void {
    const array = <FormArray>objectRegistrationForm.controls["children"];
    const group = <FormGroup>array.controls[index];
    group.controls["field"].setValidators([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.maxLength(20)],
    [customValidatorAsync(customObject, objectRegistrationToSave.children[index].id)]);
}
```

should be without the extra ][ between the regular and custom validator in setValidators.

```
setFieldValidators(index: number): void {
    const array = <FormArray>objectRegistrationForm.controls["children"];
    const group = <FormGroup>array.controls[index];
    group.controls["field"].setValidators([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.maxLength(20),
    customValidatorAsync(customObject, objectRegistrationToSave.children[index].id)]);
}
```